# convert php secure stream socket to nodejs

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I have a problem with nodejs secure socket.
I have php program to create secure socket server and a client can connect to it for processing, but I want to convert program to nodejs but nodejs is not working.
when I use tcp socket the client create connection to server and node server receive data and print it but data is encrypted.
when I'm secure the socket with tls server started but client data was not received.
here is php socket config please help me to convert it to nodejs.

```
$instance->server = stream_socket_server(ssl://127.0.0.1:8000, $errno, $errstr, STREAM_SERVER_BIND | STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN, $context);

context is returned by this function

public static function getSSLContext() {
        global $rootPath;
        $pemPassphrase = 'passphrase';
        $pemfile = $rootPath . '/server.pem';

        $context = stream_context_create();

        // local_cert must be in PEM format
        stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $pemfile);
        // Pass Phrase (password) of private key
        stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'passphrase', pemPassphrase);

        stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', true);
        stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);
        return $context;
    }
```

Comment: If you want people to help you with your Node code, then include your Node code alongside with all of the errors and other symptoms  instead of PHP. If you want other people to write the code for you then this is not the right place.

Comment: probably TCP server/client in Nodejs is not configured correctly. Post relevant code.